# Occasional ChromeDriver error when using Cucumber.js --parallel option

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumberjs

I have a UI test framework written in Selenium WebDriver JS, with test scenarios in Cucumber.js. I'm having an occasional issue when running these tests in Chrome and using the experimental --parallel CLI option. I tend to use --parallel 5 to speed up the overall execution time of the tests and this works well in all other browsers than Chrome, where the tests will sometimes end suddenly with the message

Error: EADDRNOTAVAIL connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1:60730 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)

At that point the browsers remain open but the Cucumber process ends.

I know the --parallel option is experimental but I can find no other mentions of this online so I want to make sure I'm not doing something stupid.

I'm using:

Chrome 73.0.3683.103

ChromeDriver 73.0.0

Cucumber 5.1.0

Selenium WebDriver 4.0.0-alpha.1

(installed from npm).

This is on macOS 10.14.4 if that makes a difference. I can replicate this on other machines with the same OS version too, have not got a Windows machine to hand to try.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest instead of using Selenium WebDriver JS with Cucumber that you use Protractor with Cucumber. Protractor is a JS wrapper of selenium and there is a project that has already done all the hard work of combining cucumber and selenium. Protractor has built-in parallel functionality that was built to run parallel browser testing. Check out https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in selenium-webdriver that is now fixed in master.